# Nested lookarounds to circumvent lookbehind maximum bound

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a specific item in a string using a flavor of JavaScript regex that allows lookbehinds, but I believe I am messing up the lookarounds, possibly in the nesting of them or I'm using the wrong lookarounds altogether.

Here is the regex I have put together so far:

```
(?<=<a class="" href="/voice/m/contact/(?=\S*?))([\s\S]*?)(?=</a>)
```

Here is a snippet of the string I am trying to pull the match from:

```
<b>

<a class="" href="/voice/m/contact/dhbte4tgsbhh65u6">Name</a>
</b>
```

In the above example, the regex is matching `dhbte4tgsbhh65u6">Name` when I want it to match `Name`. I somehow need it to *not* include the `dhbte4tgsbhh65u6">` which is being matched by `(?=\S*?)`.

How can I fix my regex to do what I need?

Comment: [You cannot parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1229023)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?!.*?\/voice\/m\/contact\/\w+[^a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z\s\d]*.*)(?<=>)[a-zA-Z\s\d]*
```

Try this. See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/22

Comment: That would work if the snippet I included were the only thing I needed to match from, however it is just part of a longer string that includes multiple `</a>` tags, so unfortunately, that regex will not work. I need to ensure it matches only the characters following `/voice/m/contact/dhbte4tgsbhh65u6">` like my example. The trouble, of course, is that the sequence of letters/numbers after /contact/ varies.

Comment: @HeatherLeigh try now.changes made.

Comment: That would be great, except sometimes the `Name` is more than one word, thus it has a space. When I test that regex with more than one word in the `Name` area, it doesn't work. Also, is there any way to do this without groups? I'm using the regex to search for what I need and put it in a variable in an Android program called Tasker and I believe the last time I tried using a group it didn't work so I was avoiding them.

Comment: @HeatherLeigh try now.it will except few words including intergers.removing groups would be though.

Comment: Darn, it's perfect except I just tested it in my application and indeed, groups are not supported. It spit out the entire `/voice/m/contact/dhbte4tgsbhh65u6">Name</a>`. Are there any other methods to match just `Name` that you can think of?

Comment: @HeatherLeigh does it support lookbehinds?

Comment: Lookbehinds yes, but not variable lookbehinds.

Comment: @HeatherLeigh its not actually correect.it will work for other tags as well.

Comment: Marking yours as the answer because you tried very hard to meet my needs and I'll be using a variation of yours in my final solution, I think!

Answer (score 0):

Lookahead will do zero width match it won't match any character. So when you use this regex `(?<=<a class="" href="/voice/m/contact/(?=\S*?))` it first checks that the string `contact/` is followed by zero or more non-space characters. If yes, then it looks after the `contact/` string which was actually located inside `<a class="" href="/voice/m/contact/`. So this lookbehind,

```
(?<=<a class="" href="/voice/m/contact/(?=\S*?))
```

Sets the matching marker just after to the string `contact/` and captures all the space and non-space chars `([\s\S]*?)` upto the next closing `</a>` tag.

If your language supports `\K` then you don't need to use a lookbehind to extract the `Name` part.

```
<a class="" href="/voice/m/contact/[^>]*>\K([\s\S]*?)(?=</a>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sE4iH3/4)

Comment: That makes sense. What other regex can I use in place of the lookahead to match just the `Name`?

Comment: lookarounds are use only for condition checking purpose. If you use a lookahead instead of `[^>]*`, it won't be possible to match the string `Name`. `[^>]*` Matches some chars, but a lookahead won't match any charcter..

Comment: Ah, I see. Are there any other methods outside of lookarounds to match `Name`?

Comment: you could use `\K` if your language supports. `<a class="" href="/voice/m/contact/[^>]*>\K([\s\S]*?)(?=</a>)`

Comment: Oh, I did see that in your edit. I forgot to mention that my language does not support \K. It's a variant of the JavaScript flavor of regex (with the addition of lookbehinds). Any other options or am I out of luck?

Comment: use this `<a class="" href="/voice/m/contact/[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)(?=</a>)` and get the string `Name` from group index 1.

Comment: Groups, unfortunately, are not supported in the application I'm using. Anything else or have I now reached the end of my choices?

Comment: does your language supports variable length lookbehind?

Comment: if yes, then you could use `(?<=<a class="" href="/voice/m/contact/[^>]*>)[\s\S]*?(?=</a>)`

Comment: It supports lookbehinds, but not variable lookbehinds.